# Self-hosted Open-source Machine Learning tool for detecting normal behavior and anomalies in syslogs?

Tags: open-source

I am currently doing an internship with a company and I have been given the task of finding a self-hosted and open-source machine learning tool that can detect normal behavior and anomalies in syslogs.

The tool should be able to learn what is considered "normal" behavior based on a set of training data and then be able to detect any deviations from that normal behavior as anomalies. The company requires the tool to be self-hosted and open-source.

I have been searching online, but I have not been able to find a tool that meets these requirements. Can anyone recommend a self-hosted and open-source machine learning tool that is specifically designed for this task?

Ideally, the tool should be easy to use and have a user-friendly interface. Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.